# Needing to parse out data

Tags: sql

I am trying to parse out certain data from a string and I am having issues.

Here is the string: 
1=BETA.1.0^2=175^3=812^4=R^5=N^9=1^12=1^13=00032^14=REP NOT FOUND ON REP TABLE, CANNOT INSERT TO REPRGR.^10=107~117~265~1114~3143~3505~3506~3513~5717^11=SA16~1~WY~WY~A~S~20100210~001~SE62^-omitted due to existing Rep Not Found

I need to return this "REP NOT FOUND ON REP TABLE, CANNOT INSERT TO REPRGR."

Here is my query `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5000),CHARINDEX('14=',Column))FROM Table`

Comment: Do you have to do this in SQL? Can't you do it in your application.

Comment: yeah i have to in sql

Comment: Assuming this is SQL Server (you don't mention what DBMS you are using) you need to use `SUBSTRING` in conjunction with `CHARINDEX`..  `CHARINDEX` only gives you the index of the first instance of the string in question.

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using; MS SQL, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, etc?

Comment: Okay let me rephrase this ^14= contains information that I need to parse out but it isnt consistent in length or words. So some rows will be ^14= Invalid phone number. While other rows are like stated above. So pretty much i need to grab whatever is in ^14= nothing before or after it. If that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get the value of argument 14.  This should do it:

```
select substring(
  someData
  , charindex('^14=',someData) + 4
  , charindex('^',someData, charindex('^14=',someData) + 4) - charindex('^14=',someData) - 4
) errorMessage
from myData
where charindex('^14=',someData) > 0
and charindex('^',someData, charindex('^14=',someData) + 4) > 0
```

Try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/22f23/2

This gets a substring of the given input.
The substring starts at the first character after the string `^14=`; i.e. we get the index of `^14=` in the string, then add 4 to it to skip over the matched characters themselves.
The substring ends at the first `^` character after the one in `^14=`.  We get the index of that character, then subtract the starting position from it to get the length of the desired output.

Caveats:  If there is no parameter (`^`) after `^14=` this will not work.  Equally if there is no `^14=` (even if the string starts `14=`) this will not work.  From the information available that's OK; but if this is a concern please say and we can provide something to handle that more complex scenario.

---

Code to create table & populate demo data

```
create table myData (someData nvarchar(256))
insert myData (someData) 
values ('1=BETA.1.0^2=175^3=812^4=R^5=N^9=1^12=1^13=00032^14=REP NOT FOUND ON REP TABLE, CANNOT INSERT TO REPRGR.^10=107~117~265~1114~3143~3505~3506~3513~5717^11=SA16~1~WY~WY~A~S~20100210~001~SE62^-omitted due to existing Rep Not Found')
 , ('1xx^14=something else.^10=xx')
```

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 113
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Try it now; it seems some of the data you're running it over doesn't have any matches.  The `where` condition will filter out such results.

Answer (score 1):

If you're parsing, can we assume that you don't know what might come after the '^14=', but you need to capture whatever does? So searching for a particular string won't work because anything could come after '^14='. The best approach is to identify the longest reliable specific string that gives you a "foothold" to find the data you're looking for. What you don't want to do is accidentally capture the wrong data if the '^14=' appears more than once in your string. It looks like the '^' is your delimiter, since I don't see one at the start of the string. So you were actually on the right track, you just need to use SUBSTRING as a commenter mentioned. You also need to identify a marker for the end of the error message, which looks like it might be the next occurring '^', correct? Check several samples to be sure of this, and make sure the end marker doesn't at any point exist before your start marker or you'll get an error.

```
SELECT CAST((SUBSTRING(Column,CHARINDEX('14=',Column,0),CHARINDEX('^',Column,CHARINDEX('14=',Column,0) + 1) - CHARINDEX('14=',Column,0))) AS VARCHAR(5000)) FROM Table
```

You may need to increment or decrement the start position and end position by doing a +1 or -1 to fully capture your error message. But this should dynamically grab any length error message provided you are positive of your starting and ending markers.

I also have here a table-valued parsing function, where you would pass it the string and the '^' and it will return a table of data with not only the 14=, but everything.

```
CREATE   function [dbo].[fn_SplitStringByDelimeter]
(
     @list      nvarchar(8000)
    ,@splitOn   char(1)
)  
returns @rtnTable table 
(

    id int identity(1,1)
    ,value nvarchar(100)
) 
as  
    begin   
        declare @index int
        declare @string nvarchar(4000)
        select @index = 1        
        if len(@list) < 1 or @list is null  return        
       --
         while @index!= 0        
         begin        
              set @index = charindex(@splitOn,@list)        
              if @index!=0        
                    set @string = left(@list,@index - 1)        
              else        
                    set @string = @list        

              if(len(@string)>0)   
                    insert into @rtnTable(value) values(@string)        
                --
              set @list = right(@list,len(@list) - @index)        
              if len(@list) = 0 break        
         end    

        return
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a Case When statement with wildcards to find the value that you want.

Example:

```
SELECT 
 CASE
    WHEN x LIKE '%REP Not Found%'
        THEN 'REP NOT FOUND ON REP TABLE, CANNOT INSERT TO REPRGR'
 ELSE 
    ''
END AS x
```

FROM 
    #T1

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query (assuming `MySQL` database):

```
-- item is the column that contains the string
select SUBSTR(item, LOCATE('REP',item), LOCATE('REPRGR.',item) + LENGTH('REPRGR.') - LOCATE('REP', item)) info_msg from Table;
```

**Illustration:**

```
create table parsetest (item varchar(5000));

insert into parsetest values('1=BETA.1.0^2=175^3=812^4=R^5=N^9=1^12=1^13=00032^14=REP NOT FOUND ON REP TABLE, CANNOT INSERT TO REPRGR.^10=107~117~265~1114~3143~3505~3506~3513~5717^11=SA16~1~WY~WY~A~S~20100210~001~SE62^-omitted due to existing Rep Not Found');

select * from parsetest;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| item                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1=BETA.1.0^2=175^3=812^4=R^5=N^9=1^12=1^13=00032^14=REP NOT FOUND ON REP TABLE, CANNOT INSERT TO REPRGR.^10=107~117~265~1114~3143~3505~3506~3513~5717^11=SA16~1~WY~WY~A~S~20100210~001~SE62^-omitted due to existing Rep Not Found |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

select SUBSTR(item, LOCATE('REP',item), LOCATE('REPRGR.',item) + LENGTH('REPRGR.') - LOCATE('REP', item)) info_msg from parsetest;
+------------------------------------------------------+
| info_msg                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| REP NOT FOUND ON REP TABLE, CANNOT INSERT TO REPRGR. |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```